# Are there situations in which a low-quality answer should not be downvoted?

Tags: support, users, votes

#### Scenario 1

- I see a high-quality answer by *userB*
- I visit userB's profile and view their other answers
- I vote accordingly
- UserB gets a lot of upvotes in a short period of time
- The end

#### Scenario 2

- I see a low-quality answer by *UserY*
- I visit UserY's profile and view their other answers
- I vote accordingly
- UserY gets a lot of downvotes in a short period of time
- SE bot detects targeting and undoes my votes
- I create a question for it and get accused of being 'on a slippery slope' by other meta users

In reading the responses to my last [question](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2220/why-were-my-1s-turned-into-1s), it seems to be the general consensus that just the fact that I decided to view all of UserY's answers means that I am 'targeting' that user.

Am I using SE incorrectly?

I do not understand what the point of downvoting is if I'm being discouraged from downvoting low-quality answers.

Comment: Being one of the responders to the previous question, I'm voting this up. By the way, the scripts would _also_ be triggered in the first scenario. Lots of upvotes by a single user, for a single user - they get reversed too. Just like lots of downvotes.

Comment: @S.L.Barth Good to know. I guess I haven't crossed that threshold yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> "it seems to be the general consensus that just the fact that I decided to view all of UserY's answers means that I am 'targeting' that user"

By your own admission, you are. The question seems to be if that's a bad thing.

Look, the automated systems got triggered, and the trigger was not wrong. I am not sure where the threshold is, but at some point, you crossed it, regardless of your justification. I, as a mod, can't change that for you.

My advice is similar to what others have said: If you naturally come across things you want to downvote, go ahead. But to purposely seek out one users answers and downvote in a large block, you are going to trigger the automated systems. It does not mean that your votes are unwarranted, it's simply that an automated system got triggered.

I would not read too much into the event.